# TFS 2008, Space issue

Tags: team-foundation-server

In our data tier of TFS infrastructure, the folder C:\data\TfsWarehouse.0.db has grown upto 2 gb. Since C: drive is of only 10 gb ..can we move this folder to some other drives. Can we delete the files of subfolder of TfsWarehouse.0.db. Or is there any other method to create some space.

Thanks upfront
Kabir

Answer (score 1):

You have all the options that SQL Server gives you:

- Add another db file to the database (and set the current to fixed size to prevent it growing) on a different disk.
- Move the db file
- Add another (transaction) log file on a different disk
- Move the log file
- Move the whole database

The move options will likely require shutting down TFS for the move. Adding another file can be done live.

The options are not mutually exclusive.

See SQL Server Books Online for details. [This is an overview of files and filegroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx).

Comment: @ Richard- Thanks

The TFS databases are in different drive altogether. This Folder C:\data\TfsWarehouse.0.db conatains several other folders which mainly consist of XML files, asstore and other type of files. Is it advisable to delete these files to create some space?

Comment: @kabirrao: I see nothing like that on my (small scale) TFS instance. Maybe these are connected with activity tracing options in TFS? In which case they are likely to be temporary files that have not been cleaned up. But you will need to verify that first...

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the File Structure of the Analysis Services Database named TfsWarehouse.
You can move this in SSMS using a detach - attach process just like a regular SQL database.

There are a couple of other ways of moving the database listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280670.aspx)